# how to position a div with respect to bottom of browser window

Tags: css

I have some blocks of div with different heights and want to position a div say "scroll" that should be 100px above the bottom of the window irrespective of the window size in each block of div. how to do it in jquery?

Comment: you can do that with pure css

Answer (score 3):

You can use css

```
#scroll {
         position:fixed;
         bottom:100px; 
        }
```

Comment: i want it to be at the bottom the of window so user can see the "scroll" div with out scrolling the page. if i am not clear enough please let me know

Comment: perhaps i am not able make the seen clear for you let me explain i have 3 block of div and each have different size of content and then i have a div called "scroll" in each block of div now i want that "scroll" div to be visible 100px above the bottom of the window even if the content is more then the height of the window and that will be the case for each block of div

Comment: So what css support multiple element with position:fixed;

Comment: Can you not add the `postion: fixed` to multiple elements?

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski what do you mean?